# SQL Server stored procedure: how to return column names/values of type failures in variable?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Ambiguous thread name, I apologize. I am not new to SQL, but I'm new to coding longer stored procedures so I don't deal with variables much outside of passing through maybe a table name or returning row count, etc.

I have a stored procedure that is executing an insert from a staging table to a fact table. There are a couple type casts in the insert.

If the insert fails due to a typecast. Is there any way to return the name of the column that failed, along with what the failed value was? How would I code that? I know that Try_parse would make it so the stored procedure doesn't fail on type cast failure, but I want to be able to pass back exactly what column and value failed.

I show an example here:

```
Create Procedure dbo.Example_Insert
    @updateUser  varchar(255)
As 
Begin
    Insert Into dbo.Energy_Costs (Energy_Cost_Id, Project_Id, Propane_Cost_Dollars,
                                  Electricity_Cost_Dollars, Fuel_Savings_Evaluator)   
        Select
            Next Value For energy_cost_id,
            r.project_id, 
            Cast(r.propane_cost_dollars As Decimal(18,2)),
            Cast(r.electricity_cost_dollars As Decimal(18,2)),
            @update_user fuel_savings_evaluator
        From 
            staging_table r

    return @@ROWCOUNT
end
```

Comment: Do the `select` without the `insert` using `try_cast()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURSOR in sql then insert one line at a time. When insert fail return value currently row error.
I hope my idea suitable with you.